# Kubuntu 19.04 boot up with unable to enumerate usb error and device descriptor read/64, error -32

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, kubuntu

I've installed Kubuntu 19.04 on my laptop and increased the size of my root partition recently,also I'm using Kubuntu ppa for latest kde updates.

Here is the log:

```
 ak@ak-pc:/var/log$ cat dmesg
```

https://pastebin.com/uespCFhq

Is there something wrong with it,

I'm also getting the dev/sda6: clean,blocks error on startup

Recently I got device descriptor error also:

```
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  i2c_hid i2c-DLL0651:00: i2c-DLL0651:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  i2c_hid i2c-DLL0651:00: i2c-DLL0651:00 supply vddl not found, using dummy regulator
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:00: WQBC data block query control method not found
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  r8169 0000:07:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ahci 0000:00:1f.2: version 3.0
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD5000LPVX-7 1A01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GU90N    A1B0 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device not accepting address 5, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device not accepting address 6, error -32
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  usb 1-1-port5: unable to enumerate USB device
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  dell-smbios A80593CE-A997-11DA-B012-B622A1EF5492: WMI SMBIOS userspace interface not supported(0), try upgrading to a newer BIOS
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x60
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ath: Country alpha2 being used: 00
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ath: Regpair used: 0x60
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
20/08/19 11:46 PM   kernel  checking generic (e0000000 410000) vs hw (e0000000 10000000)
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325020.969:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/haveged" pid=782 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325020.969:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=783 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325020.969:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=783 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325020.989:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ippusbxd" pid=784 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.033:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=789 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.157:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=785 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.157:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=785 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.225:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.225:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  audit: type=1400 audit(1566325021.225:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=793 comm="apparmor_parser"
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  usb 1-1.5: device descriptor read/64, error -32
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 4 was not initialized!
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Extension 3 was not initialized!
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Processing 2 was not initialized!
20/08/19 11:47 PM   kernel  uvcvideo 1-1.5:1.0: Entity type for entity Camera 1 was not initialized!
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR: device descriptor read/64, error -32](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500194/error-device-descriptor-read-64-error-32)