# ERROR: device descriptor read/64, error -32

Tags: usb

ERROR: device descriptor read/64, error -32

Trying to install Ubuntu and I get "ERROR: device descriptor read/64, error -32"

Like 7 times in a row follow by.

Unable to enumerate USB device

Comment: When I search for that error message I see quite a few suggestions for solutions. Which have you tried already? [Here](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) are some more tips on asking questions on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is verifying ISOs downloaded from the official website worthwhile?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/993407/is-verifying-isos-downloaded-from-the-official-website-worthwhile)

Comment: You've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're trying to install, nor how you wrote your ISO to media (*some methods reformat the ISO which can make it work on some hardware & not others, you've provided no clues*), but back to basics.. did you verify your ISO prior to write?  did you verify the write of ISO to media? (*method here varies on specifics you didn't provide*), but your error message implies a prior step was likely at fault; or your *unstated* chosen product wasn't the best for your *unstated* hardware (*Various installer/stack options exist chosen thru ISO used*)

Answer (score 1):

`device descriptor read/64, error -32` specifically indicates a permission issue. The operating system lacks the necessary permissions to access the device. This prevents Ubuntu from reading the essential information for operating system installation.

Troubleshooting steps:

1. If your system has Secure Boot enabled, it might restrict booting from unauthorized devices like a live USB. Disable Secure Boot temporarily if possible, so that it won't affect security.
2. Connect the live USB to a different port on your computer. Some USB ports might have different power delivery limitations.
3. Recreate the live USB using a different USB creation tool or method.
4. Boot in Legacy mode. Many BIOSs offer a "legacy mode" that can bypass certain restrictions that are sometimes enabled by default in UEFI mode.